# Android: Day view calendar in drag and drop event

Tags: android, calendar

I want to make one app, that day view implement, With some features want to add, Like when tap on calendar day view that time at position on view popup, as like event view, and that view can be zoom with calendar row zoom, with left hand side hours also show as 15 min differences according zoom level.

I have try many examples  as like WeekView. Single day view. If any one know about that, then give answer, or comment reference links. Thanks you.

Comment: Can you show a similar app?

Comment: This is probably not a good question for StackOverflow. It is a bit broad and you will probably find that high-rep users are reluctant to answer. You might have better luck asking about just one of the requirements you mentioned above. Make it really clear what you want and include your research about the problem and what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Try this library :https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/5228

I hope this is what you need, if not please give some reference of what you want.